# Converting Input data to dictionary (no single delimiter)

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to convert an file.txt into dictionary. I know if the delimiter is only used one time, Then the code is as follows:

```
dict = {} 
with open('file.txt') as input_file:
for line in input_file:
    entry = line.split(":")  
    dict[entry[0].strip()] = entry[1].strip()
```

However, how do you turn a input file into a dictionary with no clear delimiter?

**file.txt:**

```
cats****5
doggie**6
ox******7
```

**output:**

```
dict = {'cats':5,  'doggie':6, 'ox':7}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply split on your delimeter as before, but take the first and *last* field:

```
for line in input_file:
    entry = line.split("*")  
    dict[entry[0].strip()] = entry[-1].strip()
```

Negative indices fetch elements from the back of the list - the index `-1` is the last element, `-2` is the second-to-last element, and so on.

---

You can also use unpacking, which allows for self-documenting variable naming:

```
for line in input_file:
    key, *_, value = line.split("*")  
    dict[key.strip()] = value.strip()
```

Here, `*_` consumes an arbitrary number of values - but not the first or last, since `key` and `value` are before and after it and both consume exactly one value. The symbol `*` denotes the arbitrary size, while `_` is a regular name that is just conventionally used for unused values.

---

If your delimiter also appears in the value, splitting is not robust. Use a regular expression to define the grammar of your delimiter, and capture key and value. For example, if your delimiter is `.` and you expect float values, the following works:

```
import re

kv_pattern = re.compile(r'^(.+?)\.+(.+?)$')
#                           ^   ^   ^ capture shortest match for any character sequence
#                           ^   ^ longest match of delimiter sequence
#                           ^ capture shortest match for any character sequence

data = {}
input_data = ['cats....5.0', 'doggie...6', 'ox.......7.']
for line in input_data:
    key, value = kv_pattern.match(line).groups()
    data[key.strip()] = value.strip()
```

Comment: Can you edit to elaborate what you mean by first and last field - what exactly is -1 doing here?

Comment: For unpacking, does "key, *_, value" tells it that key is before " * " and value is after it?

Comment: @raymai I‘ve added some basic explanations on negative indices and unpacking with *. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MisterMiyagi. However, if my value is 0.6, then the value is still showing 6 if i use line.split("."). How can I fix that?

Comment: @raymai Can the delimiter occur only in the value or in the key as well?

Comment: only in the value

Comment: @raymai Added an example of using ``re`` to parse an ambiguous delimiter.